# Angular Signals: How to handle requests to API

Tags: angular, rxjs, signals

So I am new to signals and I am trying to use them more and more in our application. The part where I still cannot wrap my head around is the connection between rxJS and Signals. Because we are using angulars HTTP client, we have to deal with observables (which is not a bad thing). But now I am trying to make my code more reactive by updating a signals value by doing an API call whenever the ID of the scoped object(which is a signal itself) changes. This is what I came up with:

```
 effect(() => {
      this.apiService.hasSomething({
        customerId: mySignalWhoseValueChanges()
      }).subscribe(value => this.mySignal.set(value));
    });
```

If i use `mySignal()` in my template and change `mySignalWhoseValueChanges()`, it will call the `effect()` because `effect()` listens for any signal changes that are used within it.

The thing is, I am 100% sure there is a better approach without using `effect()`, but I just do not know. I tried using `toSignal()` but this does not work as its not actually a signal thats referenced, but only the value at the time of creating it, or am I missing something:

```
this.mySignal = toSignal(this.apiService.hasSomething({
      customerId: mySignalWhoseValueChanges()
    }))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think is indicated to use "effect" on HTTP responses. They recommend it only in some situations https://angular.io/guide/signals#use-cases-for-effects . So stick to traditional development from my point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine a signal with an http request pretty easily.

You can use the `toObservable` function to watch for changes in/on the signal, then trigger your http request when the id changes.

**Note:** Signals are **NOT** meant to be a replacement for RxJS (at least not anytime soon). They are meant to work in unison.

To this this, you would take the following steps:

1. Create a `user` signal to watch for the current user. (this can be anything I chose a number).
2. Create a `response` signal to watch for the http response.
3. Next create a way to update the user (I chose a form input) that binds to the `user` signal.
4. Use `toObservable` and pass your `user` signal as the parameter.
5. When it changes make your http request to the server.
6. When the server responds, update your `response` signal with the data.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-with-signals?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
import { toObservable } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [HttpClientModule, FormsModule, AsyncPipe, JsonPipe],
  styles: ['div{font-family: monospace}'],
  template: `
    @if ({request: page$ | async}) {
      <div>{{response() | json}}</div>
    }
    <p>Enter a number from 1 to 4.</p>
    <input [(ngModel)]="user" />
  `,
})
export class App {
  user = signal<number>(0);          // A way to watch users
  response = signal<any>(undefined); // A way to watch for http changes

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

 
  page$ = toObservable<number>(this.user).pipe( // Watch for user changes
    filter((id) => id > 0),                     // Only make http request for users larger than 0
    tap((id) => console.log('user id', id)),    // Just some debugging
    exhaustMap((id) =>                          // Don't execute the http request if one is already in progress
      this.http
        .get<Response>(`https://example.com/user/${id}`) // Make the http request
        .pipe(tap((response) => this.response.set(response)))   // Update the response
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: With your approach, the request will only execute once. if you would for example put example.com/endpoint/customerId as an URL, even if customerId updates(which is a signal in my case), the request wont execute again, or am I missing the point?

Comment: @MartinHochmair Looks like my last comment about updating the answer didn't save... But anyways, I updated the answer which should address your comment.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for! I was hoping for a straightforward approach but this is definetly better than effect.